# Is is possible to modify the maven console output to hide the [INFO] logging?

Tags: maven-2, logging

I was wondering if it was possible to modify the output from maven to for example hide the lines that start with [INFO] or to be able to see lines that start with [DEBUG]?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to configure it as a logger but mvn -q hides the [INFO] lines and mvn -X shows the debug messages.

Update in 2015: newer versions of maven have added a config file where this is finally possible although as a global per install configuration, check on your $mavenInstallationDir/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties if the file doesn't exist then your maven version is probably too old, I believe it was added on the 3.1 release

Answer (score 32):

You can activate debug output using `-X` or `--debug`. For example:

```
mvn -X install
```

You can hide `INFO` messages using `-q` or `--quiet`. For example:

```
mvn -q install
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes! Finally I can get clean output from `java:exec`.

Answer (score 6):

try grepping the output, e.g.
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v "^\["

Answer (score 3):

From their own docs, you want this:

```
RESULT=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo $RESULT
```

For reference, see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html#forceStdout

Comment: Irrelevant when not using help:evaluate.