# How to change maven logging level to display only warning and errors?

Tags: maven-2, logging, maven

I want to prevent maven from displaying INFO messages, I want to see only WARNINGS and ERRORS (if any).

How can I achieve this, preferably by changing the command line that calls maven?

Comment: Relevant topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069/can-maven-be-made-less-verbose/40535065#40535065 . `-B, --batch-mode` or `-q` will make `mvn` less verbose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is is possible to modify the maven console output to hide the \[INFO\] logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116659/is-is-possible-to-modify-the-maven-console-output-to-hide-the-info-logging)

Answer (score 141):

## Answering your question

I made a small investigation because I am also interested in the solution.

## Maven command line verbosity options

According to http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-verbose-option

- -e for error
- -X for debug
- -q for only error

## Maven logging config file

Currently maven 3.1.x uses SLF4J to log to the System.out .
You can modify the logging settings at the file:

```
${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties
```

According to the page : http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

## Command line setup

I think you should be able to setup the default Log level of the simple logger via a command line parameter, like this:

```
$ mvn clean package -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug
```

But **I could not get it to work**. I guess the only problem with this is, maven picks up the default level from the config file on the classpath. I also tried a couple of other settings via System.properties, but all of them were unsuccessful.

## Appendix

You can find the source of slf4j on github here : [slf4j github](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j.git)

The source of the simplelogger here : [slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/e14afa68f0857ddc3dd925a1cf7c28c17184069d/jcl-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.java)

The plexus loader loads the `simplelogger.properties`.

Comment: did you get the `simplelogger.properties` change working? When I change the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.warnLevelString` setting `mvn compile` updates appropriately, but it appears to be ignoring the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel` setting. It also logs at the info level, even when i set that to warn or error.

Comment: @Alden, I am getting the same behaviour.  it is simply ignored.

Comment: For me it turned out that adding "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info" to the build command does not have any effect. If I define this before the build in MAVEN_OPTS like this: export "MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug", then it works perfectly without changing the ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties file.

Comment: Alden, Gábor Lipták: and for me none of the two methods work. :( I am using Maven 3.2.5.

Comment: if windows, in bat file ,use set MAVEN_OPTS=%MAVEN_OPTS% -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn

Comment: Bingo, `-X` was overpowering `--quiet` for me.

Answer (score 41):

> Edit: this answer was from **2013**, there are probably better ways to do this now, please consider the other answers.

### Linux:

```
mvn validate clean install | egrep -v "(^\[INFO\])"
```

or

```
mvn validate clean install | egrep -v "(^\[INFO\]|^\[DEBUG\])"
```

### Windows:

```
mvn validate clean install | findstr /V /R "^\[INFO\] ^\[DEBUG\]"
```

Comment: but if the point is to reduce the redundant IO during mvn... then it's not really does the trick

Comment: How can we achieve the same on Windows machine as egrep doesn't work on it?

Comment: something like `mvn validate clean install | findstr /V /B "\[INFO\]" | findstr /V /B "\[WARN\]"`

Comment: Looks like `findstr` supports regex and other options that might make it more succinct - https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: `mvn validate clean install  | findstr /V /R "^\[INFO\] ^\[WARN\]"`

Answer (score 38):

You can achieve this with MAVEN_OPTS, for example
`MAVEN_OPTS=-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn mvn clean`

Rather than putting the system property directly on the command line.  (At least for maven 3.3.1.)

Consider using `~/.mavenrc` for setting `MAVEN_OPTS` if you would like logging changed for your login across all maven invocations.

Comment: This seems to work as I could disable warning and info message by setting the level to error, but unfortunately it also turned off the regular output. I was actually trying to disable some warnings while running `help:evaluate` target to print the value of `project.version` and this output (though doesn't seem to come through `slf4j`) also got turned off.

Comment: The only answer that works without permanently messing with Maven installation. Another reason Maven is a dinosaur among the build system - it just doesn't have support for common sense requirements.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Logback, just put this `logback-test.xml` file into `src/test/resources` directory:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 15):

you can achieve this by using below in the commandline itself

```html
 -e for error
-X for debug
-q for only error
```

e.g :

```html
mvn test -X -DsomeProperties='SomeValue' [For Debug level Logs]
mvn test -e -DsomeProperties='SomeValue' [For Error level Logs]
mvn test -q -DsomeProperties='SomeValue' [For Only Error Logs]
```

Comment: Would have been good to have more info, like does this enable or disable the corresponding log

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to upgrade to [Maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options) or higher to take advantage of the `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config` support.

Then you can use any options from Maven's SL4FJ's [SimpleLogger](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) support to configure all loggers or particular loggers. For example, here is a how to make all warning at `warn` level, except for a the PMD which is configured to log at `error`:

```
cat .mvn/jvm.config
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.net.sourceforge.pmd=error
```

See [here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) for more details on logging with Maven.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian this worked for me like a charm to change the log level for Maven 3.6 at runtime without having to change the `simplelogger.properties` file:

```
MAVEN_OPTS='-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error' mvn test
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even with maven 3 the only way to do that is to patch source code.

Here is short instruction how to do that.

Clone or fork Maven 3 repo: "git clone https://github.com/apache/maven-3.git"

Edit org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli#logging, and change

```
cliRequest.request.setLoggingLevel( MavenExecutionRequest.LOGGING_LEVEL_INFO );
```

to

```
cliRequest.request.setLoggingLevel( MavenExecutionRequest.LOGGING_LEVEL_WARN );
```

In current snapshot version it's at line 270

Then just run "mvn install", your new maven distro will be located in "apache-maven\target\" folder

See this diff for the reference: https://github.com/ushkinaz/maven-3/commit/cc079aa75ca8c82658c7ff53f18c6caaa32d2131

Comment: This answer is OBSOLETE as of now - a) repo URL has changed, b) there is no INFO level statement in this code, c) diff URL doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't matter where the code uses INFO - when developing plugins, your mojo should rely on the maven logger with `getLog()` - if you can live with the configurability.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `info` to `error` in `simplelogging.properties` file will help in achieving your requirement.

Just change the value of the below line

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
```

to

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error
```

Comment: Downvoted as this is a change of the source, whereas I believe the poster wanted a command line method, I certainly do!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `simplelogger.properties` in `${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/` and set the following properties:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.Sisu=warn
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.warnLevelString=warn
```

### And beware: `warn`, not `warning`

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed when using the 2.20.1 version of [the maven sunfire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), all warnings are written down to a dumpstream file. e.g. `/myproject/target/surefire-reports/2017-11-11T23-02-19_850.dumpstream`