# How to disable debug logs when bulding maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, logging

I want to hide `DEBUG` logs while building maven project with test case on the command prompt using `mvn clean install` command. Only `ERROR` logs should be visible.

I am looking for a solution that also applies when building maven project with test cases.

Comment: Than the configuration for logging in the tests must be changed. You can try `mvn -q` but this prevent other output as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, but -q prevent other output, so can't use it.

Comment: See this....

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors>

Comment: mvn -q does not work for test cases

Comment: Isnt your testcase logging is controlled by log4j specified by you?

Comment: @VinayLodha how to control test case logging using sl4j ?

Comment: That will dependent on which impl of slf4j you are using. In case you are using log4j over slf4j you can control it by modifying log4j.properties