# How to stop INFO level log in maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

When Maven RUNS the Assembly plugin it gives lot of output of INFO level. can any body suggest how to change the Level of Plugin to WARN or ERROR rather then INFO.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19319402/1570834. It provides various options for changing the logging of maven.

Comment: oh i know the -q switch but problem is that it quit all debug log, I just want for assembly plugin. because i have almost 30 dependency jar files. maven assembly assembles all of them in one jar so it logs INFO level for each on file in details. so i want this INFO to quit only for assembly plugin.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why would you like to change that?

Comment: because it slows down any annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the logging component of the Maven assembly plugin. The solution is to use a later version of the plugin - for example, version 2.5.5. So add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.5</version>
```