# Disable 'downloaded' logs in Maven Invoker tests

Tags: java, maven, logging, maven-invoker-plugin

I'd like to tune down logging during Maven Invoker tests. Right now logs are polluted with sequence of `Downloading` and `Downloaded` for every dependency in every test separately.

```
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-grouper/2.19/surefire-grouper-2.19.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-grouper/2.19/surefire-grouper-2.19.jar (38 KB at 1292.5 KB/sec)
```

I want to preserve all other logs, so `mvn -q` is not an option. Also, `--batch-mode` hides just downloading progress, not `Downloading` and `Downloaded` logs.

Comment: did you check couple of answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors for some hints? Short answer to your question would be: it is not possible. It would be possible with scripting on top of Maven (i.e. if your question was mostly about CI builds)

Comment: You'll only get those logs once. After those dependency are installed in your Maven repo, you won't have them anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
```

to `MAVEN_OPTS` should help with that. At least in maven 3.2.3 and 3.3.9 (those were the ones I've tested).

Comment: right, it helps! But only if `invoker.mavenOpts` are declared before `invoker.goals` in `invoker.properties`. Very strange behavior for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your build is done on an Unix like environment and you can change how Maven is invoked, you can pipe the Maven output to `egrep`:

```
mvn <goals> | egrep -v ' Download(ing|ed): '
```