# How to mute log level from minify-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, logging, minify

Is there any option similar to the maven "--quiet" option to mute or reduce the log output of the minify-maven-plugin?

This plugin creates 3 lines of log entries per JS file, e.g.

```
[INFO] Creating the minified file [Formatter.js].
[INFO] Uncompressed size: 1365 bytes.
[INFO] Compressed size: 526 bytes minified (259 bytes gzipped).
```

This is a matter of optimisation for us as we slowly lose overview of what's actually relevant in our logs. I do not see, how any of the logged information could be of use when logged for each single file.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't scale well with large web project` ? Yes you might get a longer log output but this is usually not a problem? Apart from that I would open a issue against the github project for that ?

Comment: There is no way to do this at a plugin level, but you can do it at the project level, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the question and will open a github project issue.