# Maven fails when I try to show less log messages - Need I change more lines in logging settings? How can I see anything?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, logging

According to [How to change maven logging level to display only warning and errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors) I had set `simplelogger.properties` in maven/conf/logging/ to:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.Sisu=warn
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.warnLevelString=warn
```

And I run the Clean target.

It runs. Without WARNs, INFO only.

After that I am changing the single line in `simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn
```

And rerun Clean. There should be no log messages and there aren't any. I am waiting a bit... and getting the red line:

```
Process terminated
```

If I run Package instead, I see some WARN log messages, and somewhere closer to the end, the whole buffer is erased and I am getting the same red line. Lone and red.

Used terminals: `git-cmd.exe` from `git bash` and the default `cmd.exe`

Delegating build/compile to maven turning on/off does not change anything.

Obviously, I need to change correspondingly some other properties in `simplelogger.properties` or some settings elsewhere. But which ones? I don't see anything except "Process terminated"

Comment: I hit similar case.  Running a maven job of a previous running program.  I saw the output of the maven build showing but at the end all got cleared but only leaving the red line of Process terminated.

Comment: As a result, for 4 months already I launch maven from the command line only. Upgrade and reinstall of IntelliJ did not help. And I don't want to reinstall all on the comp. If you will find any solution, please, mention it here!

Comment: hey i'm not sure whether you're having same situation as mine.  on the "run" window there is a parent node of the item "Process terminated".  clicking on the parent node it shows back all those error output.

Comment: Wow! Really it does show. I did not notice. Thank you, now I can try to find the reason... Please, put that as an answer. I edited the question header so that your comment can be an answer.

Comment: Good to know it helps.  I've put it into an answer.  Thanks a lot, Gangnus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "run" window there is a parent node of the item "Process terminated". clicking on the parent node it shows back all those error output.