# The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory with travis build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, travis-ci

My goal is : mvn -q spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e

i am getting below error
[image: Error in travis build]

Travis full build :  https://travis-ci.org/github/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST/jobs/715649594#L855

My project directory: https://github.com/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST

With .travis.yml below goals are working perfectly

- mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml clean verify -Pjacoco coveralls:report
- mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
- mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=JosephThachilGeorge_TDDTEST
- mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pfailsafe

Only i have problem with end to end test goal :  mvn -q spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e

My project pom is in below location: https://github.com/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST/tree/master/spring-project

Comment: Did you mean to execute `mvn -q -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e` instead of `mvn -q spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e`?

Comment: mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e  and  

mvn -q spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e

I tried above both goals , in both case i am getting above error

Comment: Can you please link to the failed `travis`-run using `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e`?

Comment: @JosephGeorge > cd spring-project  then run `mvn -q verify -Pe2e`. I tried to run you code using mvnw - but its huge project.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it will execute `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e` since you use this command multiple times in `.travis.yml`.

Comment: [Just as I said...](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/717994622/log.txt) --- `The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated.` - This is a different error. I would suggest You reduce the log level of your tests.

Comment: @Turing85  Yes i tried withn "mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e"  below is my log : https://travis-ci.org/github/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST

Comment: That is a different error/question (see my last comment). [Please limit yourself to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: @Turing85  when i am giving "mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e"  travis is showing "The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated" It is not a big project , i have only 3 e2e test. Theses e2e tests are working in eclipse build

Comment: It is a limitation imposed on you by travis-ci. Again: reduce the log level for whatever e2e test framework you are using.

Comment: My .travis.yml link is : https://github.com/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST

Comment: I tried to change the goal to reduce build size, But error "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM "

Comment: I tried to reduce log with the help of below link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors                       But i got travis error "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM"

Comment: @Turing85 Is there any way can i reduce the log level of travis using mvn command ?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. You have to configure your e2e framework/its logger to reduce its log level.

Comment: Move your project pom file into the root location of your project.. than you can use the defaults. Makes life easier.