# maven: disable surefire console errors (or fix console errors encoding)

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

i have maven project that just runs some groovy-based tests

it has Cyrillic testcase names and assertion text

as a result the surefire report `TEST-dbtest.DBSourceTest.xml` correctly generated in `UTF-8` encoding with Cyrillic chars - as expected

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<testcase name="get connections" classname="dbtest.DBSourceTest$1" time="0.301"/>
<testcase name="заповнення тарифів" classname="dbtest.DBSourceTest$1" time="0.269">
<failure message="_1C.firstRow(sql).count_fail==0 По кожній культурі ..." type="Assertion failed">
    <![CDATA[Assertion failed: 
    assert _1C.firstRow(sql).count_fail==0
           |   |        |    |         |
           |   |        |    303       false
           |   |        /*
           |   |        для всех:
           |   |        По кожній культурі ...
```

but in console i see the question marks `?` instead of Cyrillic chars for all exceptions occurred during tests even i specified encoding `UTF-8` everywhere i know.

```
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   ?????????? ???????
assert _1C.firstRow(sql).count_fail==0
       |   |        |    |         |
       |   |        |    303       false
       |   |        /*
       |   |        ??? ????:
       |   |        ?? ?????? ???????? ...
```

i tried different versions

the surefire plugin `2.21.0` prints all the Cyrillic to console with question marks

the surefire plugin `2.12.4` prints the test summary correctly but failed assertions with question marks

```
test: .\sql\checksource\AB-01-заповнення тарифів.sql
...
Tests run: 15, Failures: 9, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.772 sec <<< FAILURE!
Assertion failed: 
assert _1C.firstRow(sql).count_fail==0
       |   |        |    |         |
       |   |        |    303       false
       |   |        /*
       |   |        ??? ????:
```

SO, I want to achieve one of:

- disable failed assertions output to console
- fix console output encoding for failed assertions to UTF-8

below is my current config

i tried to disable the console output but errors with question marks still there..

pom.xml:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dbtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbtest</artifactId>
    <name>dbtest project</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

command line to start maven:

```
mvn clean test -q -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 1>log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: What is your OS? I mean what OS are you running your maven script?

Comment: Also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4116659/460557

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937410/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos, thanks for your comments. that's pointed me to the solution. finally report output encoding fixed with `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` environment variable. was not succeeded  to disable errors on console fully.